# Android Transparent activity issue

Tags: android, android-activity

i have two activityes in my app A1 and A2 , i want to start activity A2 from A1 but A2 needs to be transparent  and A1 blured , here is the code what i tryed but it doent work

```
public void setTranslucent(){
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that by that way, you have to inflate that new xml file by using LayoutInflator, and simply set the alpha alpha of current one xml ParentView.

Comment: but i saw in APIDemos that is posible

Comment: I said its possible, but not through the way you do. just inflate the xml, that you are using in activity 2, and change the alpha of xml file that you are using in activity 1.